# What protocol does RDP on Windows 7 use for copying files via the clipboard?

Tags: file-io, rdp

When I copy a local file and paste it to a remote computer through an RDP session (both clients are Windows 7) is it transferring the file data via SMB, SFTP, or some other protocol/port?  I've poked around the RDP GUI and don't see any clear reference to clipboard transfer protocols or ports.  Just curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RDP is its own protocol, and clipboard sharing is provided by it.

From the [Remote Desktop Protocol spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383015.aspx):

> **Clipboard mapping**
>   Users can delete, copy, and paste text and graphics between applications running on the local computer and those running in a remote desktop session, and between sessions.

You can also get a full paper on the RDP protocol from MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc240445.aspx). The PDF describes the protocol in terms of the bare-bones protocol, the archive of PDFs supplies papers for the individual services that sit on top of it.

Comment: Does it use the same port (e.g. 3389)?

Comment: It's part of the same communications channel, so it should do.